# Factory pattern with generics

Tags: java, groovy, factory-pattern

I am trying to implement factory pattern with generics. I am not sure if i am implementing it right

```
interface DocumentValidator<T> {
    Boolean validate(Document document, T object)

}

class ShipmentDocumentValidator implements DocumentValidator<Shipment>{
      @Override
       Boolean validate(Document document, Shipment object) {
           return true
       }
}

class DocumentValidatorFactory {
    static DocumentValidator forClass(Class clazz) {
        if (clazz.simpleName.contains('Shipment')) {
            return new ShipmentDocumentValidator ();
        }
    }
 }
```

Calling code:

```
 DocumentValidator validator = DocumentValidatorFactory.forClass(Shipment.class)
```

I dont think i should depend on class name, but how can i implement otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Your factory can be simplified by groovy's multiple dispatch method resolution.  For example:

```
class DocumentValidatorFactory {
    DocumentValidator forClass(Shipment shipment) {
        new ShipmentDocumentValidator()
    }
    DocumentValidator forClass(Invoice invoice) {
        new InvoiceDocumentValidator()
    }
}
```

Groovy is smart enough to call the right method by looking at the parameter class at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto WillP and Ataylor. Let me add that another option is to put the creation of the validator into the class being validated. For example:

```
public interface Validation
{
  public Validator getValidator();
}
public class Shipment implements Validation
{
  ... whatever ...
  public Validator getValidator()
  {
    return new ShipmentValidator();
  }
}
public class Restock implements Validation
{
  ... whatever ...
  public Validator getValidator()
  {
    return new RestockValidator();
  }
}
public class ValidationFactory
{
  public getValidator(Validation x)
  {
    return x.getValidator();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a valid solution, but once you've done this, what value does the `ValidationFactory` add?  You would never have a situation where you could call `ValidationFactory.getValidator(x)` where you couldn't just call `x.getValidator()`.  I think the point of the factory is to be able to separate all knowledge of document validation from the documents themselves.

Comment: It separates the knowledge of validation required by the CALLER from the implementation. Yes, the things being validated have to know what their validators are, as opposed to the factory knowing what their validators are.

Comment: I kinda like this one, very OO, IMO. Though I agree with @ataylor the `ValidationFactory` is kinda useless now. Somewhat reminds me of custom validators in [Java EE's bean validation](http://www.javabeat.net/bean-validation-java-ee-creating-custom-constraints-validations/) `@Constraint(validatedBy=Clazz)`

Comment: In any case, I'm not saying this is THE right answer, just one possible solution to the same general problem. I was trying to say earlier that someone might still use a validation factory because this separates out the need for the caller to know how you get your validators, thus making it an implementation detail and not part of the API.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter were [a String](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-factory-pattern-example), then that comparison would be feasible, but in this case, you could simply compare the class:

```
if (clazz == Shipment) {
    return new ShipmentDocumentValidator ();
}
```

But you could also use a map with the class as key and the validator as value:

```
class Shipment {}
class Invoice {}
class Document {}

interface DocumentValidator<T> {
    Boolean validate(Document document, T object)
}

class ShipmentDocumentValidator implements DocumentValidator<Shipment>{
   Boolean validate(Document document, Shipment object) {
       true
   }
}

class InvoiceDocumentValidator implements DocumentValidator<Invoice>{
   Boolean validate(Document document, Invoice object) {
       true
   }
}

class DocumentValidatorFactory {
    static DocumentValidator forClass(Class clazz) {
        [
            (Shipment) : ShipmentDocumentValidator,
            (Invoice)  : InvoiceDocumentValidator
        ][clazz].newInstance()
    }
 }


assert DocumentValidatorFactory.forClass(Shipment) instanceof ShipmentDocumentValidator
assert DocumentValidatorFactory.forClass(Invoice) instanceof InvoiceDocumentValidator
```

Comment: Yes, bad idea to check for a string. There's no compile-time validation, so if you accidentally type "Shiqment" instead of "Shipment", you get incorrect results with no warning. I used to work with a system where the original programmers regularly passed around hard-coded strings, and I found numeorus cases where the code gave incorrect because they "frieght" insted of "freight", "shipment" instead of "Shipment" (note capitalizatoin -- if you missed the difference, so did they), etc.